# Review history is delayed or hidden on user activity tab

Tags: bug, review, profile-page, recent-activity

A user made [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16828206), but it isn't showing up on [their profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876504/damian-krawczyk?tab=activity&sort=reviews) as of now.

[image]

Caching gone bad? Didn't think those views were cached, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: We don't show deleted posts in that list. So when you delete things as a mod, they'll never appear there. I can't explain why the other user's action isn't appearing though.

Comment: Ah, thanks @animuson. Should have thought of that. Refocused question.

Comment: Looking at a couple other profiles, it seems like Recommend Deletion actions in particular are just not ever making it into the list. Might be a review type missing somewhere.

Comment: Yep, the SQL that generates that list has this line: `and r.ReviewTaskResultTypeId not in (1, 9, 10)` - 1 being Not Sure, 9 being Recommend Deletion, and 10 being Recommend Close. I... wouldn't be able to tell you why those two are excluded. I *can* tell you it was changed to that (from only excluding TypeId 1) on Aug 22, 2012.

Comment: @animuson If you're wanting to dig more, I'd pull a backup from a few months back and seeing if the result types changed? They shouldn't have, though, that'd show up in way too many places.

Comment: Well, the comment on the change is "user activity - don't show Delete and RecommendDeletion review task results on the user page" which is pretty straightforward that was the intended function, except yeah the IDs have changed and it's affecting both the Recommends instead of both the Deletes. Though I'm still not clear what the purpose of hiding them *always* was, instead of just hiding them when the post is deleted like already happens anyways.